# Having Issues removing border from table element that is embeded in a Wordpress Website using Elementor

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embed, elementor

So I am trying to add a countdown timer on my wordpress site that every wednesdays resets at 8:30PM to the next wednesday. I have the js figured out but when I am adding it to the website the I cannot seem get rid of all of the borders from the  element.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 25, 2023 20:30:00").getTime();


var x = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();


  var distance = countDownDate - now;


  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);



  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = seconds;


  if (distance < 0) {
    resetCountdown();
  }
}

function resetCountdown() {
  clearInterval(x);
  var nextWednesday = new Date();
  nextWednesday.setDate(nextWednesday.getDate() + (3 + 7 - nextWednesday.getDay()) % 7);
  nextWednesday.setHours(20);
  nextWednesday.setMinutes(30);
  countDownDate = nextWednesday.getTime();
  x = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}


/* added for visibility */

#count {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-style: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px;
}

td {
  width: 25%;
}

#days {
  color: white;
}

#hours {
  color: white;
}

#mins {
  color: white;
}

#secs {
  color: white;
}

#text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table border=0 cellspacing=0>

    <tr>
      <th>
        <h1 id="days"></h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1 id="hours"></h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1 id="mins"></h1>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h1 id="secs"></h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 id="text">Days</h3>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3 id="text">Hours</h3>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3 id="text">Minutes</h3>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3 id="text">Seconds</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
```

[image: Screenshot of the table]

Have tried adding all of the border atributes that I looked up. I also went under the advance tab on element to add `table{border:none;}` in the custom CSS section. I am new to wordpress so I am not sure if there is somewhere where my CSS is being overwritten or if I am messing up the css in the embed itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I run your snippet, no borders are visible. So that's not helpful. Perhaps you need to include a link to your site, so we can have a look at it running in place.

Comment: @BrettDonald I just added the link to the website I am working on in the post. I did noticed the same thing when I was developing the js in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style rule in your web page is causing the borders to appear:

```
td, th {
    padding: 8px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

You can override this with a rule to target just that one table:

```
table#test1 td, table#test1 th {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of that I did
`table, td, th {
    border: 0px;
}`
This ended up working for me. Thanks for the help pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
{border: none !important;}
```

if it didn't work create an ID specifically for the table you are referring to and call that specific ID on CSS.

edit: it would be important to add `!important` when you have to override elementor default CSS.

Comment: Tried doing this both in the <style> CSS portion of the embed and also in the Custom CSS section under the advance tab. neither worked. Thank you for the info on the !important tag tho!

Comment: Added the ` border: none !important; ` to the td portion of the custom CSS section and got rid of some more of the border on the second row.